# how to create criteria for fetching data from two table using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to fetch data from two tables using this query in hibernate:

```
select info.gwid,info.companyId,info.gwUserId,info.create_dt,stat.status,stat.lastactivity from gwinfo as info JOIN gwstatusinfo as stat ON info.gwid=stat.gwid
```

I tried like this hibernate:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from SBoxInfo sinfo,SBoxStatus sstatus on sinfo.gwId = sstatus.gwId");
List<SBoxInfo> listOfSBoxs = (List<SBoxInfo>)query.list();
```

but it's not returning the list in SBoxInfo type. Do i have to create a criteria for that?
How to create criteria for above query to retrieve the result in SBoxInfo type list?

Comment: shouldnt your 'on' be a 'where'?

Comment: What is the relationship between those two tables?

Comment: one-to-one relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by creating criteria like this:

```
Criteria ct = session.createCriteria(SBoxInfo.class);
ct.setFetchMode("SBoxStatus", FetchMode.JOIN);
List<SBoxInfo> listOfSBoxs = ct.list();
```